# Why do i need RewriteCond in my .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

Why do i need RewriteCond in my .htacces file because it can work without it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/?$ a?album_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially
you write this to clean up and prettify the url so it is free of things like "?" and album_id like things that are for developers not for common people they see the url like

album/1

instead of

a?album_id=1

Rewrite condition here say that url should not be of a directory or a file, so may be you arent giving any of them so it is working fine, it is just a extra check for future that it must not be a "file" ie -f or "directory" -d

Comment: yes, it works without this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d